# Get values from one specific prometheus target (e.g. CPU load)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, quarkus

Using grafana and prometheus, with multiple (quarkus) services are written and listed inside prometheus, how can I grab values form one of this services?
[image]

Actually I can grab data from all services like this

`topk(5, max(scrape_duration_seconds) by (job))`

[image]

Using this dashboard variables
[image]

But now to get the CPU load of one of this services, I tried different queries but not of them are fetching the CPU load of just one service instance.
I tried queries like this:

`sum(base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent{job="servicename"})`

`topk(5, max(base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent) by (job))`

But none are working.
What is the right grafana query to get values from one service/job from the prometheus list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want any one metric: you can use `topk(1, max(base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent) by (job))`. You'll get the biggest one.

If you want specific one you could use something like `base_cpu_processCpuLoad_percent{instance="some.server.lc:8099"}, job="some_job"`